# How to compute derivative/gradient of matrices? E.g. $w^T X^T Xw - 2w^T X^T t +t^Tt$?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, vector-analysis

How to compute derivative/gradient of matrices? E.g. $w^T X^T Xw - 2w^T X^T t +t^Tt$?

Intuitively $2w^TX^Tt$ looks like $2xy$ so the derivative would be $2X^Tt$.

But what about $w^TX^TXw$?

---

$X$ is $\mathbb{R}^{n \times (p+1)}$. $w,t$ are row/column vectors corresponding to "weights" and "predictors" in $w^T x=y$ sense.

The gradient is $\frac{\partial}{\partial w}$.

Answer (score 2):

$w^TX^Tt = t^TXw$ is linear: its gradient is $t^TX$.

$w^T(X^TX)w$ is quadratic: its gradient is $2X^TXw$.

**Edit:** consider $f(w)=w^T A w$ for a symmetric matrix $A$. Then
$$
f(u+v)-f(u) = (u+v)^TA(u+v) - u^Tau = 2u^TAv + v^TAv = 2u^TAv + o(|v|),
$$
so $f'(u)v = 2u^TAv$.

Comment: Yeah but how do you see that $w^T(X^TX)w$ becomes that without "opening" all the multiplications?

Comment: @mavavilj I've added details

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=(Xw-t)\,\,$ then the function is
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= y^Ty \cr
d\phi &= 2y^Tdy = 2y^T(X\,dw) = 2(X^Ty)^Tdw \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial w} &= 2X^Ty = 2X^T(Xw-t) \cr
}$$